# Wrong user returned in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I asked few people in work, but noone could help me. So here it is.

I'm on domain. Windows authentication. Deny anonymous.

I start my app on local webdev server. Then try to access it. So...

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>
<%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
```

in my .aspx page..

When I access this (in this example I just want to see my name of logged user), I get my username, just like expected. But when I want to "test" my app - still running in first account - and I access it in another browser (no, I'm not stupid, ofcourse under another windows accout, made for testing) I'm getting the first username still. So the problem is: User.Identity.Name returns name of user where I started the app, not name of user who accessed it via browser.

Any tips? :)

Have a nice day

Comment: I think the *still running in first account* is your problem. Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: it means: I run it in on one account, where the Visual studio runs - and webdev server runs. Then I access this running app via another user account. Is it a bit more clear? (I can't access app which is not running on server :) )

Comment: @Marty: integrated web server can't properly handle Windows authentication. Switch to IIS instead.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks for this tip. Damn it, I'm at work. Developing software:) and need to test it on local. Even my boss tried to solve this, according to him (and me too) it should work normally. But maybe I'm a special guy:)

Comment: You can install IIS locally (it's built in to Windows).

Comment: Or you can use IIS Express, which is a command-line version of IIS :)

Comment: Okey, gonna try it guys. Hope this helps:) will let you know in few minutes

Comment: I LOVE YOU GUYS :) really thank you. I would like to mark as answer, but you just commented. Please, @WiktorZychla, can you make an answer? I will vote for you ;)

Comment: @Marty: I did. Glad this really solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer (as suggested by comments above the question) would be:

The integrated web server doesn't handle Windows authentication properly. IIS should do better and recognize different users. The source of the problem is then the integrated web server.

Answer (score 0):

Output Caching is a common cause: user B might be getting a cached copy of the page generated for user A.

Comment: It has nothing to do with caching. It's disabled and even if I access different pages (for first time), it's there. Anyway, thanks for your time.